# Displaying multiple images in a popup

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uiimageview, popup

I have a button on the top of my image view.
I need to display multiple images in a view when the button is clicked; this view will be like a small popup. Can any one tell me a good way to do this?

I think showing multiple images in a `UITableView` will look like a design problem. Can any one tell me if there are any controls in Objective-C to display images in small popup?

Also, I need to get the image name/details when I click in the pop up.

Comment: if you click the button, will it always display the same number of pictures?

Comment: that makes it a bit trickier, but i suppose the same logic will work.  i'm going to write up a potential answer

Answer (score 0):

This view where you want to display the images -- you will most likely want to initialize it with `UIImageView` instances.  If you had a set amount of pictures, you could just align them how you like within IB, but if they change, you'll have to do it dynamically within the code.

So when you are creating the view to display your images, you'll want to pass the images in an array to your view controller that displays them. Using the count of the array, you can figure out how many `UIImageView` instances to create (and set up some logic how/where you want to display them on the screen).  Then you will want to set the images into their respective image views.  In order to tap to get information on the images, you'll want to add a gesture recognizer to each image view that calls a method when tapped.  You can use the same method for each and tag the image views to know which you are looking at.  for example:

```
- (void)imageViewTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    int myImageTag = [gesture.view tag];  // this will return the tag of the imageView it is associated with
    // get infomation about it's image ([gesture.view image] will give you the UIImage in it)
    //any other code you may want to implement;
}
```

That's pretty much the logic behind what it sounds like you'll want to do.  It shouldn't be too hard, but I hope this helps you out